Custom \newtcblisting with "listing and listing" option?
From the manual, I see there is "listing and comment" option as seen in the following example.
Update: with full code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{Gold}{rgb}{1.0, 0.84, 0.0}
\definecolor{Goldenrod}{rgb}{0.85, 0.65, 0.13}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{gitexample/.style={listing and comment,comment={#1}, skin=bicolor, boxrule=1mm,fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black, frame style={draw=black,left color=Gold, right color=Goldenrod!50!Gold}, colback=black,colbacklower=Goldenrod!75!Gold, colupper=white,collower=black, listing options={language={bash}, aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt,nolol,  basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries,extendedchars=true}}}
   
\begin{tcblisting}{title={Snapshot of the staging area},
     gitexample={The option `-a' automatically stages all tracked and modified
                 files before the commit.\par
                 This can be combined with the message option `-m'
                 as seen in the third line.}}
   git commit
   git commit -a
   git commit -am 'changes to my example'
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}


What I would like to do is have a "listing and listing" option.  Does something like that exist?  Something like a Python code snippet in the upper part and a bash snippet in the lower part.

You could use two lstlisting environments inside a tcolorbox:
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{Gold}{rgb}{1.0, 0.84, 0.0}
\definecolor{Goldenrod}{rgb}{0.85, 0.65, 0.13}

\tcbset{
 skin=bicolor, 
 boxrule=1mm,
 fonttitle=\bfseries,
 coltitle=black, 
 frame style={draw=black,left color=Gold, right color=Goldenrod!50!Gold},
 colback=black,
 colbacklower=Goldenrod!75!Gold, 
 colupper=white,collower=black,
}
   
\lstset{
  language={bash},
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  nolol, 
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries,
  extendedchars=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title={Snapshot of the staging area}]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
git commit
git commit -a
git commit -am 'changes to my example'
\end{lstlisting}
\tcblower
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
some python code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


